# Unable to turn on Nook HD+ after third trim attempt (Cyanogenmod 10.1)

Tags: nook, nook-tablet

After initiating my first trim attempt, I left my device alone for a bit assuming that it might take awhile to complete the process. Upon returning to the device, however, it would not power on. After trying the basics without success (holding the power button + home button to reset, etc.), I left the device alone for awhile and later found that the device had booted itself up and was running properly again (though the trim didn't work). I trimmed again after booting up and the operation succeeded almost immediately, fixing the lag issues I was having.

It's now about a month later and I attempted another trim which froze my device (no screen activity, system clock unchanging). After about 15 minutes of waiting for a change, I powered down the device, plugged it in, and went to sleep. Attempting to power the device on has been impossible, and plugging in the charger simply shows a green light (even after unplugging the device for awhile). If I hold the power button for about eight seconds, the green light turns off until I press the power button again.

When plugged into my PC via USB cable, Windows continually sounds the device connect and disconnect jingles and says "the last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it." This stops if I hold the power button as previously mentioned.

After leaving it alone for awhile, I found that the device had randomly powered on, but was stuck at the initial Nook loading screen. Powering it down left me in the same position as before.

I'm all ears if anyone has a clue on how I can proceed, or where I can ask for knowledgeable support. Thanks!